# Copy Row of data based on two conditions to a sheet which is opened by ID or URL

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have a code that helps me copy a row of data based on a condition in a given column. I have a sheet called "Master" which has around 1000 rows of data. I want to move a row of data to a sheet called "Master Responses" if column 1 of "Master" has the word "Positive" or "Negative" in it. I used the or function (||) in the IF STATEMENT to select the condition (that is if "Positive" is entered or "Negative") but the row is only copied when I type "Positive" in the first column. When I type "Negative" in the first column the row is not copied. Also, I wanted to know how the code should be modified if I had to call the "Master Responses" sheet by using ".openByID or .openByURL". I have attached the code, please feel free to edit it. I am new to scripting and have been stuck on this for over a month. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function onEdit()
{
  var sheetNamesToWatch = ["Master"];
  var columnNumberToWatch = 1;
  var valuesToWatch = ["Positive"];
  var valuesToWatch1 = ["Negative"];
  var targetSheetsToMoveTheRowTo = ["Master Responses"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if(sheetNamesToWatch.indexOf(sheet.getName()) != -1 && 
  valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue()) != -1 || 
  valuesToWatch1.indexOf(range.getValue()) != -1 && range.getColumn() 
  ==columnNumberToWatch)
  {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetsToMoveTheRowTo[valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue())]);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 
    sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about .openByID or .openByURL, however this should fix the problem with "Negative".

I also added extra parenthesis on the first if statement so that it was clear to me what it was checking on.

```
function onEdit()
{
  var sheetNamesToWatch = ["Master"];
  var columnNumberToWatch = 1;
  var valuesToWatch = ["Positive"];
  var valuesToWatch1 = ["Negative"];
  var targetSheetsToMoveTheRowTo = ["Master Responses"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if((sheetNamesToWatch.indexOf(sheet.getName()) != -1) && ((valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue()) != -1) || 
  (valuesToWatch1.indexOf(range.getValue()) != -1)) && (range.getColumn() ==columnNumberToWatch))
  {
    if (valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue()) != -1)
    {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetsToMoveTheRowTo[valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue())]);
    }
    else
    {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetsToMoveTheRowTo[valuesToWatch1.indexOf(range.getValue())]);
    }


    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 
    sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```